# Subtract from date field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff, dateadd

I have a field receiveddate which is a datetime data type. I am trying to return results 7 days back from that date. So basically I want to see anything with a received date of today back 7 days. I tried several things including 
     `c.ReceivedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-7, GETDATE()) AND getdate()` but its pulling results from 2011! Im using SQL Server 2008. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you substitute GETDATE() with a fixed date, say in yyyy-mm-dd format (or yyyy-dd-mm), are the results still wrong?

Comment: Maybe your sys clock is off... what do you get with `select getdate()`

Comment: @hypnos yes still wrong. I changed it to c.ReceivedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-3, '2016-12-09') AND '2016-12-09'

Comment: Can you post your entire code... i'm betting the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @scsimon it appears correct I got 2016-12-09 15:11:28.770

Comment: @scsimon you would be correct! I just saw what I did..thank God its Friday! Thank you!

Comment: No sweat tia, glad you found your problem

Answer (score 0):

you code should be

```
c.ReceivedDate BETWEEN (GETDATE() - 7) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: This is no different than the original code of the OP.... it will not change the results